# How can I pass function call in a component as a prop in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, mern

I am trying to pass my function `updateProfile` as a prop in the Button component shown below. The function is not working and the application crashes when I press the button.

Here is the code of button component.

```
const Button = (props) => {         
    return (            
         <>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.buttonContainer}
                disabled={props.disabled}
                onPress={props.functionCall}
            >
                <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{props.title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>             
        </>         
    );  
 };
```

And here is how I am using

```
<Button disabled={isLoading ? true : false} functionCall="updateProfile" title="Edit Profile"/>
```

The function

```
const updateProfile = () => {
    navigation.navigate("updateProfile", member);
};
```

Actually, I have many buttons and each button has different function call. So, it needs to be sented through props. Help needed!

Comment: Try to pass function like this: `functionCall={updateProfile}`

Comment: You are passing it as string.. pass it as a function in {}<Button disabled={isLoading ? true : false} functionCall={updateProfile} title="Edit Profile"/>

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
functionCall="updateProfile"
```

to this:

```
functionCall={updateProfile}
```

Comment: thanks, dear, though it was a small mistake, I was trying to fix it but it took me a long time.